# How to write mongo db aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am new to mongo db. I have a collection in this format

```
{id: 1
 name:A
 age:32
 parentID:Top_1
}
{id: 2,
 name:Ba
 age:5
 parentID:4
}
{id: 3,
 name:Aa
 age:12
 parentID:1
}
{id: 3,
 name:Ab
 age:8
 parentID:1
}
{id: 4,
 name:B
 age:45
 parentID:Top_2
}
{id: 5,
 name:Ba
 age:5
 parentID:4
}
{id: 6,
 name:Ba
 age:7
 parentID:4
}
```

The parents have an ID of the format "Top_n" where n can be 1 , 2 ,3 etc..
I need to write a query to group by parent and children so that

```
 A
  children:{Aa ...}
           {Ab ...}
          ....
 B
  children:{Ba ..}
           {Bb..}
           ....
```

Not sure how i can do this using mongodb and springboot. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this group aggregation pipeline to group all the docs you have by parentId and put all the docs that have the same parent in the same document and append them to an array called children.

if you don't need the whole document you can choose just the fields you need instead of using $$ROOT.

you can check the docs to get familiar more with this pipeline :
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

```js
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$parentID"،
    "children": {
      "$push": '$$ROOT'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please choose my answer as the correct one if it helped you